# Powerbuilder: Syntax to modify SQL of a datastore

Tags: powerbuilder

I want to modify the SQL statement of a datasore and have problems with the single quotes. The new SQL should be:

```
Select 'F' as c_value from table
```

The problem ( I guess ) are the single quotes.

```
datastore.Modify( "DataWindow.Table.Select='Select 'F' as c_value from table'" )
```

From this command I get an incorrect syntax error near the F. I thik have to escape the quotes in 'F', right? But what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my recommendation:

```
ls_Select = "Select 'F' as c_value from table"
dw_1.Object.DataWindow.Table.Select = ls_Select
dw_1.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
dw_1.Retrieve()
```

Comment: If I do a `ls_sql = ids_dw_multi_search.describe( 'DataWindow.Table.SQLSelect' )` after your recommendation, I get the right SQL-String. But dw_1.getItemString ( 1, 'c_selected' ) drops ainvalid row/column error...

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, the function describe() returns a string and does not apply change in the datawindow, the function modify() applies change in the datawindow, because it collects the field of the datawindow 'c_selected' does not want to collect the field Datawindow 'c_value', as indicated in your question?

Comment: sorry, this was an copy/pase error. The dot notation works. In the datastore i now the correct SQL. Your answer is right. 

Now i want to do a getItemString on c_value and expected to get an 'F'. But instead it says invalid Datawindow row/column. I guess this is because the c_value is not in the table-definition, right?

Comment: You do not need to be in the definition of the table, you have to keep in mind that you are using AS, an alias, if the table exists and has records with just typing: dw_1.getItemString (1, 'c_value') should return as a result The letter F.

Comment: That is what I expect. But it doesn't. If i type the code in your answer and in the next line  `dw_1.getItemString( 1, 'c_value' )`, then there is a Error. And yes, there are 6 records.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
datastore.Modify( "DataWindow.Table.Select='Select ~'F~' as c_value from table' ");
```